# Javascript function not working in onSubmit for IE... getting no errors in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
function validateRequiredFields(formid) {

    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('required');

    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {

        var FieldID = inputs[i].id;

        if( document.getElementById( FieldID ).value == '' ) {

           document.getElementById( FieldID ).style.border = '2px solid #FA3811';
           document.getElementById( FieldID ).style.background = '#FAA08E';
           document.getElementById( FieldID ).focus();
           return false;

        }

    }

    return true;
   }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What actually not works? Function not calls? Have you tried to put alert() at the first line of validateRequiredFields method?

Comment: The function is not actually firing in IE at all.  I tried alerts

Comment: How are you calling the `validateRequiredFields` function? There is no indication in the code provided.

Comment: onSubmit="return validateRequiredFields('form<?=$form['id']?>')"

Comment: You know that `inputs[i] == document.getElementById( FieldID )` ? You are overly complicating things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` method is new in Firefox 3 and Safari 3.1, it doesn't exist in Internet Explorer, not even in version 9 beta.

Comment: +1 for spotting the unsupported method. Consider @burak's suggestion of using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

Comment: I reverted back to a older method using get elements by tag name.  However I am now testing with an empty function with only an alert and I still get nothing in IE

Comment: @Adam Coburn: post your updated code.

Answer (score -1):

i would consider using jQuery

```
var inputs = $('.required',document);
```

I think this could also solve your cross browser compatibility problem as well.